# PHP mail possible to reply to an email?

Tags: php, imap

I'm attempting to reply to an email from a php applicaiton.  I use php imap to retrieve emails from the mail server.  I now want to reply to those messages.  I have the `message_id` returned from `imap_fetch_overview`.  How do i use these values to reply to the email?  I tried `In-Reply-To` but when i check the email the message shows up as a new message rather than a reply to a message.

```
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
$headers = "From: <test@domain.co.uk> \r\n";
    $headers .= "In-Reply-To: ".$overview[0]->message_id."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $subject = "testing";
    $message = "test message2";
    mail( "test2@domain.co.uk", $subject, $message, $headers );
```

How do  i solve?